# How often is a number divisible without a rest?

Tags: c, math

I am currently trying to write a method which checks how often a number is divisible by 5 with a rest of 0 (e.g. 25 is two times; 125 is three times).

I thought my code is correct but it always states that it is possible one more time than it actually is (e.g. 25 is three times; wrong).

My approach is the following:

```
 int main()
    {
       div_t o;
       int inp = 25, i = 0;
       while(o.rem == 0){
        o = div(inp, 5);
        inp = o.quot;
        i++
       }
        return 0;
    }
```

I debugged the code already and figured that the issue is that it steps once more into the loop even though the rest is bigger 0. Why is that? I can't really wrap my head around it.

```
First: 25/5 = 5; Rest = 0;
Second: 5/5 = 1; Rest = 1; - Shouldn't it stop here?
Third: 1/5 = 0; Rest = 1;
```

Ah... got it. The point where the remainder is 0 is reached when the division is done with the number which results in a rest bigger zero which is after i got increased.

What is the cleanest approach to fix that? i -= 1 seems kinda like a workaround and I wanted to avoid using an if to break

Comment: Pretty sure you have undefined behavior since you never initialize `o` before relying on it in the `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `while` loop condition in :

```
while(o.rem == 0 && inp >= 5)
```

In this way your division will stop after that you are inspecting the number 5.

A suggestion: use a `const` variable to wrap the 5 ;)

Comment: Good to know that it helps ;) Please press the top arrow

Comment: 4 minutes until I'm allowed to do so :P

Comment: @gusgxrha The 4 minutes are over now.

Comment: @gusgxrha Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're using `div()` to do the division, which I had to look up to verify that it's part of the standard. I think it's kind of rarely used, and more suited for cases where you *really* care about performance. This doesn't seem like such a case, and so I think it's a bit obscure.

Anyhow, here's how I would expect it to look, without `div()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int count_factors(unsigned int n, unsigned int factor)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for(; n >= factor; ++count)
    {
        const int remainder = n % factor;
        if(remainder != 0)
            break;
        n /= factor;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%u\n", count_factors(17, 5));
    printf("%u\n", count_factors(25, 5));
    printf("%u\n", count_factors(125, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
0
2
3
```

Comment: I read that the div function is faster than modulo. Isn't that true? I thought I would adapt to it as early as possible

Comment: "Faster" in this case should not be a worry.  Correctness, cleanliness, and readability are far more important.  Regarding correctness: Shouldn't the output be 3, 5, and 25?

Comment: @gusgxrha I was wrong, it's standard, I just didn't remember and think it's kind of obscure. Don't optimize when you don't need to, code like this is better off being easy to read.

Comment: Thanks for your advice guys!

Comment: @gusgxrha Faster? A function call that still has to do division somehow will not be faster than just a modulo on anything built this century. And since `div` is used approximately never it will not be optimized by any reasonable compiler. Btw. I looked up a few C libraries I had lying around. `div` on them is implemented as: `r.qout = a / b; r.rem = a % b;` and a few branches to make sure the rounding is done according to the standard.

Comment: @Art Thanks. I think the point of the function is that a CPU might return both the quotient and remainder in the same instruction, and `div()` allows that to be exploited. Nowadays integer divisions aren't much to worry about, and for this program certainly not so I still stand by my code.

Comment: @duffymo the result `0, 2, 3` seems correct. `5^2` is 25, `5^3` is 125 and zero represents the case with a non-zero remainder.

Comment: @unwind - why calculate the remainder inside the loop? Checking it before the loop seems sufficient and spare a recalculation in each loop (when remainder is zero).

Comment: @4386427 Perhaps ... this was how the original code did it, and I like to keep close.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to know whether the input is an integer power of 5 (or in general whether `v == N^x`) and if it is, you want to calculate and return the power (aka `x`). Otherwise return 0. This is more or less a `logN` function except that it requires integer results.

I would go for code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int logN_special(unsigned int v, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int r = 0;

    if (n == 0) return 0;           // Illegal
    if (n == 1) return 0;           // Illegal
    if (v < n) return 0;            // Will always give zero
    if (n*(v/n) != v) return 0;     // Make sure that v = n^x

    // Find the x
    while(v != 1) 
    {
        v /= n;
        ++r;
    }
    return r;
}
```